# SharePoint Online Public Website

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, public-website

I read that microsoft will remove SharePoint Online Public Website. Is their any alternative solutions for public websites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct that Microsoft have removed the SharePoint public sites. Instead they suggest to get a public website from a third part provider.

Right now they suggest either [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/) or [WiX](http://www.wix.com/) from the Office 365 admin center.

The official announcement from Microsoft states the following:

> As part of the evolution of the Office 365 service, we periodically evaluate the capabilities of the service to make sure that we’re delivering the utmost value to customers. After careful consideration, we concluded that for public websites, Office 365 customers would be better served by third-party providers whose core competency is public websites. Therefore, we’ve made the difficult decision to discontinue the SharePoint Online Public Website feature so that we can focus our efforts and investments on delivering capabilities in Office 365 that will bring more value to our customers.

[Information about changes to the SharePoint Online Public Website feature in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3027254)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. But if i choose to use GoDaddy or WiX, can i use this with SharePoint Online?

Comment: That is a really good question that i unfortunate cannot answer. I guess that the 2 providers have some special site for office365 subscriptions but i'm unsure how it will work with several SharePoint services like Search, Managed Metadata and so on.

Comment: Depends what you want to do with your website. You can display items from SharePoint on your website by e.g. using the REST API. Or even create your own webservices/rest services that expose SharePoint items. The other way around is also possible, consume data from web/rest services on your website in SharePoint to display Website data.

Comment: Ok, i need to display some forms that the user is going to answer and a workflow that is sending the information in an email.

Comment: In short, Microsoft really don't want you customising and branding SharePoint sites to the level that is often required for public web sites, so they'd rather you not use SharePoint for your public facing site (upgrades are guaranteed to break them). You can use anything on the market (probably most would go for WordPress). I'm not real sure why they pointed people to GD or WiX though.